# Формирование подписи в API в одноклассниках

Tags: rest, odnoklassniki-api, одноклассники

Как вообще правильно формируется подпись для запроса к API в одноклассниках?

[Эту ссылку](http://dev.odnoklassniki.ru/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=19825756)
и этот текст:

**Вычисление подписи**

> Массив сортируется
> в алфавитном порядке по ключам Все
> пары ключей/значений соединяются в
> формате «ключ = значение» (сама
> подпись опускается, так как ее и нужно
> вычислить). Добавляется ваш секретный
> ключ, который можно найти, перейдя в
> зарегистрированное приложение в ОК и
> следуя по ссылке для вашего
> приложения. Берется md5-хеш всей
> строки. Результат переводится в нижний
> регистр.

Может кто-нибудь внятно объяснить, как это делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, есть словарь вида

```
{ 
  "user_id": "81623",
  "method" : "users.getProfileInfo",
  "fields" : "name",
  "a"      : "true"
}
```

Сначала сортируем этот массив в алфавитном порядке по ключам:

```
{ 
  "a"       : "true",
  "fields"  : "name",
  "method"  : "users.getProfileInfo",
  "user_id" : "81623"
}
```

Затем составляем из содержимого строку вида `ключ1=значение1ключ2=значение2`:

```
a=truefields=namemethod=users.getProfileInfouser_id=81623
```

В конец этой строки дописываем ваш секретный ключ (`XXXXXXXXX`):

```
a=truefields=namemethod=users.getProfileInfouser_id=81623XXXXXXXXX
```

затем берется md5 хеш от получившейся строки

```
MD5("a=truefields=namemethod=users.getProfileInfouser_id=81623XXXXXXXXX") = 87c49d88a24585aaa5e32c316a54e4b2
```

Cтрока `87c49d88a24585aaa5e32c316a54e4b2` и есть ваша подпись.

Comment: Если запрос идет с помощью access_token
md5(params_str + md5(access_token + app_secret));
в params_str не попадает access_token от только в запросе

Comment: @pankoff, я не читал что по ссылке на оф. сайте написано, но если под access_token имеете подпись запроса, то да, понятно, что она в список параметров не входит.